# columnize with ljust in python

Tags: python, multiple-columns

This is part of my script written in python:

```
print 'Url\t\tpopularity_rank\t\treach_rank\t\tcountry_rank'

urls = open(filename)
for site in urls:
    url = site.rstrip()
    data = Func(url)
    popularity_rank, reach_rank, country_rank = -1, -1, -1
    if data:
        popularity_rank, reach_rank , country_rank = data
        print '%s\t%d\t%d\t%d' % (url, popularity_rank, reach_rank, country_rank)
```

The output is something like this:

```
Url     popularity_rank     reach_rank      country_rank
test.com    228512  222347  -1
test1.com   173834  189659  -1
```

How can I get output in a nice columnize with `ljust()`?

Comment: And what would the expected output be then? What is the maximum length of the URLs?

Comment: I just want to columnize them...I don't know what the max length of urls are actually... may be 15 is good,

Comment: I would be thankful for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this - without `ljust()` and without `\t`

```
values = {
    'test.com': [228512, 222347, -1 ],
    'test1.com': [173834, 189659, -1 ]
}

print '| %-15s | %15s | %15s | %15s |' % ('Url', 'popularity_rank', 'reach_rank', 'country_rank')
print '+' + ('-'*17) + '+' + ('-'*17) + '+' + ('-'*17) + '+' + ('-'*17) + '+'

for url, data in values.items():
    popularity_rank, reach_rank , country_rank = data
    print '| %-15s | %15d | %15d | %15d |' % (url, popularity_rank, reach_rank, country_rank)
```

.

```
| Url             | popularity_rank |      reach_rank |    country_rank |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| test1.com       |          173834 |          189659 |              -1 |
| test.com        |          228512 |          222347 |              -1 |
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you don't know how long column you need use `*` in formatting string.
But you need to know all values before to find `longest`.

```
text = [ 'a', 'abcdef', 'abc' ]

longest = max( len(x) for x in text )

for x in text:
   print "| %*s |" % (longest, x)

print 

for x in text:
   print "| %*s |" % (-longest, x)
```

.

```
|      a |
| abcdef |
|    abc |

| a      |
| abcdef |
| abc    |
```

Comment: Thank you for help..but this script read a file that content of file is some urls...This is the input of this script and valus is generating by `data=Func(url)`.  Could you possibly help me over this?

Comment: Data in Value are variables and they are generating from Func(url). If you cat file.txt the output is test.com and test1.com.

Comment: I use `values` because I have no your files but more important elements are in lines with `print` - use it in your script. More impotant is number in `%15s` or `%-15s`.

Comment: If I run the script the outtput is(What I reffered in question) :`Url     popularity_rank     reach_rank      country_rank
test.com    228512  222347  -1
test1.com   173834  189659  -1` So the output is in 4 columns like what you see in question..I want to columnize them

Comment: Use `%15s` or `%-15s` or `%15d` or `%-15d`

Comment: Owww... +1 . Pardon how a bout this line(the first?) `print 'Url\t\tpopularity_rank\t\treach_rank\t\tcountry_rank'`

Comment: You can use spaces (' ') in place of `\t` or use line similar to my example `print '%-15s%15s%15s%15s' % ('Url', 'popularity_rank', 'reach_rank', 'country_rank')`

Comment: :) Have a nice dreams :)